# Programmatically Adding a Publishing Page

Tags: 2007, publishing-page, development

Has anyone at all look at uploading a file to/using an existing SPFile in the PublishingPageCollection.Add() method?

I'm referring to this override specifically:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms495757.aspx

The docs just say "File to convert to get the Page content" - how does it convert it? Does it take an existing Publishing Page just full of the mso: meta tags filled with content and bung it into the specified layout or?

**But James, Why!?**

Got a requirement where I'd like to be able to very quickly knock up a site structure, including sticking in some pre-created Publishing Pages into the site as test data (saves me creating lots of "testarticles").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be using the Document Conversion Service, wouldn't it? I can't imagine why you'd want to convert an existing Publishing Page to ... a Publishing Page. It think that overload might be for *Document* conversion.

I would suggest uploading to a document library and then invoking the Document Conversion service.

I have added a page programmatically - but not converting anything:

```
string fileName = "Somefile.aspx";
string contentTypeString = "0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2";
string pageLayoutName = "HomeLayout.aspx";
string newPageTitle = "Some Title";

PublishingWeb elevPubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(elevWeb);

SPContentTypeId cTypeId = new SPContentTypeId(contentTypeString);

PageLayout[] layouts = elevPubWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts(cTypeId);
PageLayout layout = layouts[1];
foreach (PageLayout p in layouts)
{
    if (p.Name == pageLayoutName)
    {
        layout = p;
        break;
    }
}
try
{
    PublishingPageCollection ppc = elevPubWeb.GetPublishingPages();
    PublishingPage newPage = ppc.Add(fileName, layout);
    newPage.Title = newPageTitle;
    newPage.Update();
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
//Handle page layout not found
}
```

Comment: Good point - should probably have clarified, I'll update my question.

Comment: Well, if it's just 'Lorem Ipsum' type stuff, I'd think about just creating the pages directly - as posted above - rather than using documents and converting. Obviously, if you want actual content, that gets harder.